# Set Maximum Size for CGImageRef from ALAssetRepresentation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, alasset

I am currently using the following code to get an UIImage from an ALAsset in an iOS app.

```
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [self.asset defaultRepresentation];
CGImageRef ref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
ALAssetOrientation orientation = [[self.asset valueForProperty:@"ALAssetPropertyOrientation"] intValue];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref scale:1.0 orientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation];
```

This works very well as long as the image is reasonably small (e.g. taken with the device's camera). However if the image is too large (6000px^2 and more), the app will run out of memory during this step:

```
CGImageRef ref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
```

I would like to detect this condition before the app crashes or (ideally) set a maximum size for the returned image.

I am aware that `fullScreenImage` will return a smaller image, however the app requires a much higher resolution from the image for zooming.

Furthermore, using the byte size of the asset is unreliable as highly compressed formats such as JPG may well be small in packed size but still consume too much memory if their size in pixels is high (low detail images, highly compressed images).

Any input on how to either get the dimensions of the image and detect this situation beforehand so I can cancel loading and display an error or how to get a smaller version of such a large asset would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

After some discussion in the comments.

You can obtain the files/asset's Exif info with the call

```
[asset metadata]
```

The reference I found is here [sarofox.alasset-image-metadata](http://sarofax.wordpress.com/2011/07/10/alasset-image-metadata)
The page also shows how to get individual properties.
This should allow you to get the pixel sizes before you open the file/asset.

MY OLD ANSWER:

is below, in case any one finds the idea helpful.:

This is only a guess.
 But could you not use [ALAssetRepresentation **getBytes:fromOffset:length:error:**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetRepresentation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009728-CH1-SW2)

Using byte sizes that you would expect a device camera's image would be.

Run a check with a fromOffset from the start of the file size of the file. And a length to the ( wanted maximum ) end of the file size.

Read the size in the buffer. If it is smaller than the request then you are ok.
If it is exactly the same as the range requested then there may be more left in  the file (It maybe bigger.)

If so, Run a new request of *getBytes:fromOffset:length:error:** this time with a fromOffset from the length of the last request  and new length.

You can then add the results up and determine if the whole file will be too large.

But never have a buffer/file that is too large

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The problem is that the file size of the compressed image is irrelevant. For example a PNG of 6000px*6000px which only contains white will have a very small size byte wise but become very large once uncompressed for viewing.

Comment: I see so you want to get the projected pixel size

Comment: Yes. I have updated the question to make this clearer. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: So digging around I found http://sarofax.wordpress.com/2011/07/10/alasset-image-metadata/  which seems to imply you can get exif data from the asset using [asset metadata] . If this is helpfully I will update my answer.

Comment: Yes, that helps! Please update your answer so I can up vote and mark as correct.